# How to manipulate inline SVG from vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, vuex

So, I am creating a customizing tool for cursors with Vuejs and Vuex. Currently, I am stuck in the step where I have to bind a color user is going to click on to the fill of svg cursor. I will try to cover step by step how everyhing works and what it should do.

First of all, I have different inline **SVG's** which are replacing the default **HTML cursor**. These SVG's are placed in the **Vuex state**.

[image]

Just so you know they are put like this so when the user clicks on a button on the first component, script hides default cursor and binds chosen one with **V-HTML**. Basically, I am displaying them as HTML code in the components. 

This is where the issue begins. Now, this chosen cursor displays on the second component where the user should be able to change the **fill color**. 
What I can't figure out is how can I access the property of fill in the svg's? 

I have tried to bind it **via :fill = "dataName"** but it doesn't work like that.

[image]

I am new to Vuejs but I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're inserting the inline SVG (via `v-html`) *after* the Vue compilation step, so — as you've noticed — Vue never sees that content. Without more context, it's hard to see how you could achieve what you want.

As an alternative, though, you could have all your cursors use `currentColor` for the fill color

```
<path fill="currentColor">
```

and then simply set the CSS `color` property of some containing element to the desired color